# Unable to get html textbox value on sencha touch 2.2 form panel

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

i am using sencha touch 2.2.
I am setting html in Sencha Touch on a Ext.form.Panel as below

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyFormView', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
xtype: 'MyFormView',
config: {
items:[
{
xtype: 'fieldset',
title: 'Add Form Details',
items:[
.
.
.

{
html: [
'<div class="formula-div"><input id="textbox1" type="text" class="text-box-width"/> / <input id="textbox2" type="text" class="text-box-width"/></div>'
].join("")
},
.
.
.

]
}
]
}
});
```

There is panel with a add button.
On click of that add button i am adding this form as below.

```
controller.getNavView().push(myForm);
```

I want to get the value of html textboxes.
I tried this
document.getElementById('textbox1').value
but it doesnt return any value.

When i remove the panel with add button and called form directly, i am getting this value.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the `html` config to draw a textarea like that?  You would be much better off using a `Ext.field.TextArea` component.  Docs are here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.field.TextArea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kevhender suggested, it is better that you use `Ext.field.TextArea` or `Ext.field.Text` to create text box in your project. From then, it is much easier for you to get the value of a text box just like `Ext.getCmp('ID OF THE TEXT BOX').getValue()`.

Here are some useful links for you:

http://dev.sencha.com/playpen/docs/output/Ext.form.TextField.html
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.0/#!/api/Ext.field.Text